# How to change the .Find functions return value of a cell to a text value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the .Find function to find the latest email recipient and have my macro use that to decided who to send the email to.

[image]

This is the form we use.  When someone wants to place an order a macro adds a new order sheet below the previous one.  This means there are numerous spots for a email recipient to be place.  I want to find the one closest to the bottom.

```
 Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim findrow As Long, finrow2 As Long
    Dim Emailrec As Range
    
    findrow = Range("A:A").Find("Date & Time", after:=Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row  'This searches for the date and time from bottom up
    findrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    
    Emailrec = Range("D:D").Find("Email Recipient", after:=Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    
    Set rng = Range("A" & findrow & ":H" & findrow2)
   
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Emailrec.Value
        .CC = "jblanton@vulcanforms.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "I am have it done"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Where I am having an issue is `Emailrec = Range("D:D").Find("Email Recipient", after:=Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)` .  I keep getting type mismatch errors when I use this to look for a single cell.  Than I can not use this cell in the `.To = Emailrec.Value` section.  Is there a way to use the cell output from the .Find function for the .To section of code for an email address?

Comment: Missing a `Set`.

Comment: I still get the Type Mismatch error on that line.  Does it have anything to do with me defining it as a Range?

Comment: Should be `Set EmailRec = Range("D:D").Find("Email Recipient", After:=Cells(1, 4), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)`, or you can drop the `After:=Cells(1, 4)` since the default is the cell in the top left corner of the search range. Then test if the find succeeded: `If Not EmailRec Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: If you want the actual email address, it looks like it's in one cell below "Email Recipient", so you could use `EmailRec.Offset(1).Value`. Though, your screenshot is a little confusing as I only see one email address, at the very top.

Comment: I changed the picture to better represent what I was trying to show.  I will give this a shot.

Comment: Adding the Set and removing the After:=Cells portion fixed it.  Thank you so much.